# Transferring video streaming javascript code into React (ML5)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webcam, tensorflow.js

I a trying to convert the code in the ML5 image classification example([Link](https://github.com/ml5js/ml5-examples/tree/master/javascript/ImageClassification_Video)) to my React component, which is as follows:

```
class App extends Component {
  video = document.getElementById('video');

  state = {
    result :null
  }

  loop = (classifier) => {
    classifier.predict()
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({result: results[0].className});
        this.loop(classifier) // Call again to create a loop
      })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    ml5.imageClassifier('MobileNet', this.video)
      .then(classifier => this.loop(classifier))

  }
  render() {

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
      .then((stream) => {
        this.video.srcObject = stream;
        this.video.play();
      })

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

However this does not work. The error message says that `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot set property 'srcObject' of null`.

I can imagine `video = document.getElementById('video');` is probably not able to grab the element by id. So I tried

```
  class App extends Component {
  video_element = <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>;

  ...

  render() {
    ...
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {video_element}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Which did not work either. I'm confused of what will be the correct method to implement this?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering again with an highlight on a slightly different problem rather then the `ref` one.

There is a huge problem that is causing the awful blinking and constantly failing promise due to an exception... and it is the get of the user media in the render method!

Consider this, every time you set the state, the component is re-rendered. You have a loop that constantly update the state of the component, and that promise keeps failing.

You need to get the user media when the component gets mounted:

```
componentDidMount() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => {
    if (this.video.current) {
      this.video.current.srcObject = stream;
      this.video.current.play();
    }

    ml5.imageClassifier("MobileNet", this.video.current)
       .then(classifier => this.loop(classifier));
  });
}
```

Your render method is then a lot shorter:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <video ref={this.video} id="video" width="640" height="480" autoPlay />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you so much for your help and detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

In the moment `App` is instantiated the video element doesn't exist yet, but the `document.getElementById` runs, returning undefined or null. That's why you get:

```
Cannot set property 'srcObject' of null
```

Because here:

```
this.video.srcObject = stream
```

`this.video` is null.

This is not the proper way of doing this. You should prepare a reference of the dom element, assign it as a prop and then access the element from there. Something like:

```
class App extends Component {

  video = React.createRef()

  ...

  render() {

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
      .then((stream) => {
        if ( this.video.current ) {
          this.video.current.srcObject = stream;
          this.video.current.play();
        }
      })

    return (

      ...

      <video ref={ this.video } 
             id="video" 
             width="640" 
             height="480" 
             autoplay
      />
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the reference problem. But when I pass that into `ml5.imageClassifier('MobileNet', this.video)`, it says I'm not passing in the video element. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Using a ref, you should use `this.video.current`

Comment: Yes I've tried that, but it keeps showing errors of `App.js:32 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException` and `index.js:1582 Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.`

Comment: Sure! `https://codesandbox.io/s/j1vx7y3l7v` Here's the link. You might have to open the preview window to activate the webcam part.